# _layout page - default all pages to center - auto width

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Can someone tell me what I can add the _layout page to have all my pages center align and adjust to 100 % depending on the resolution? Is this possible. I think it might be in:

Thanks!

```
    .container {
        width:90%;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `margin:auto;` on your `.container` div.

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:auto;
  width:90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<p>
Header
</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
<p>
some text
</p>
<p>
some more text
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<center>` HTML tag like this in your `_Layout` page

```
<center>
    @RenderBody()
</center>
```

This will center the content of all views/pages that use that layout.

For more information take a look at this [HTML center tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp).